# Find big O when $f(n)= \log(n^4+1)$

Tags: calculus

Found this site: http://people.math.sc.edu/binev/Fall06/Q8s.pdf which claims that big to $f(n)$ is $\log(n)$,
but I don't understand how $\log(n^{4}+1)\leq  C \log(n)  $ wont $\log(n^{4}+1)$ win the struggle then $n$ gets big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for $n>1$,
$$\log(n^4+1)\leq \log(n^5)=5\log(n).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you understand why I'm being downvoted?

Comment: @stenvik team I do not know. I edited the formulas in your question, so now it is better looking.

Comment: There are quite a few temperamental persons on this site…